# Certain values are not visible in MPAndroidChart?

Tags: android, bar-chart, mpandroidchart

I am using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) to display my charts, in the barchart it displays some values perfectly but for some other values, the bar is visible and can be highlighted but its value is not visible.

Any clue please on how to fix this ?

This is a picture to clarify what I am saying. The red areas is where the bar is visible but not its value.
[image: charts]

Comment: try this dataSet.setDrawValues(true);

Comment: Am using a MarkerView to show the values, but even with marker view some of the bar's values like shown in the picture are not displayed.

Answer (score 2):

Before setting the data (sorry I couldn't find the data in your question):

```
graph.setVisibleYRangeMaximum(barDataSet.getYMax() + 20, YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);
```

replacing `20` with the height of your custom layout.

Comment: Nice answer +1. I edited the formatting slightly for you :-)

Comment: @David Thanks for your comments

Comment: @Raj what is the unit of measure for that 20 please.

Comment: Occurs the issue in line chart mostly bar chart not arise the issue. Set some hardcoded value the values are not hide that's way i'm using 20.  So finally yaxis max value is maximum of y dataset+20.                                                                               And my answer is suitable for this question only hard coded may be varied.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem and this is how I've solved it.

```
float maxValue = barSet.getYMax();
int extraSpace = (int) (maxValue / (yVals.size() + 3));
chart.getAxisLeft().mAxisMaximum = (int) maxValue + (extraSpace < 1 ? 1 : extraSpace);
```

`yVals` is the list of Y axis values, while you can play with `+3` so the whole chart view seems OK according to your layout.